# Jquery on element loaded via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

Jquery makes it easy to register callbacks on events happening in a doc. However, in one of the apps we're building, we need to register callbacks on existing elements in the page, but also on elements that are loaded later via Ajax upon user actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery 'live' http://api.jquery.com/live/

Let's you do exactly what you are trying.

Bob

Answer (score 1):

You can re-register the events after success or use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)